# Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value

Tags: apex, json, time

I'm trying to parse a Time field from my lightning component to my apex controller by using JSON and deserializing it in apex into an existing Object.

But unfortunately I'm always getting the error

> Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 10:30:00.000Z

I already tried different Time formats and with/without quotes "" in my JSON

- 10:30
- 10:30:00
- 10:30:00.000
- 10:30:00.000Z
- T10:00:00.000Z
- 2018-06-07T10:00:00.000Z

But nothing works.

- My Org is on Spring 18 API Version 42
- I have an SObject (Event__c) with a Time Field

The problem is reproducable in anonymous apex with following code

```
Event__c workingObject = new Event__c();
workingObject.Name = 'Lorem';
workingObject.Public_Start_Time__c = Time.newInstance(10,10,10,10);

String serializedObject = JSON.serialize(workingObject);
String mixedObject = '{"Public_Start_Time__c": "' + workingObject.Public_Start_Time__c + '", "name": "Ipsum"}';
String manualObject = '{"Public_Start_Time__c": "2018-06-07T10:00:00.000Z", "name": "Dolor"}';
try {
   Event__c banana = (Event__c)JSON.deserialize(serializedObject, Event__c.class);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());
}

try {
   Event__c banana = (Event__c)JSON.deserialize(mixedObject, Event__c.class);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());
}

try {
   Event__c banana = (Event__c)JSON.deserialize(manualObject, Event__c.class);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());
}
```

which results in the 3 following messages

> Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 10:10:10.010Z or request may be missing a required field
>
> Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 10:10:10.010Z or request may be missing a required field
>
> Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 2018-06-07T10:00:00.000Z or request may be missing a required field

Everything I found so far was for dates or datetimes but not time only.

Comment: Have you tried serializing your object and debug the format of the Public_Start_Time__c (for the format)?It seems it doesn't work well with serialization as it is a beta field type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug, and I'd recommend contacting Salesforce Support (If you haven't already).

Heres a repo I wrote using a custom object (`Test__c`, with a single time field, `Some_Time__c`). It starts with the a demo using `Time` as the object, then runs the same code for `Test__c`. The raw `Time` object works, and has the same syntax as the JSON, but the JSON object fails with the same message.

```
Time t = DateTime.now().Time(); 
String s = JSON.serialize(t); 

System.debug(s); // "13:50:40.848Z"

Time t2 = (Time)JSON.deserialize(s, Time.class);

System.debug(t2); // 13:50:40.848Z

Test__c test = new Test__c(
    Some_Time__c = DateTime.now().Time()
);

String testString = JSON.serialize(test);

System.debug(testString);
// {"attributes":{"type":"Test__c"},"Some_Time__c":"13:50:40.850Z"}
// "13:50:40.850Z"

Test__c result = (Test__c)JSON.deserialize(testString, Test__c.class);
```

---

Some additional notes from my test runs:

- Using `Map<String, Object> record = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(testString);` returns a valid `Time` string in the map.
- Trying to access this with `System.debug((Time)record.get('Some_Time__c'));` fails with a:

  > System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Time
- Since theres no `Time.Parse` method, I cant figure out a good way to get the string value back into a `Time` object

---

I spent some time writing an actual parser, which detects field types & behaves accordingly (using the fancy new `switch` statement). This should cover most use cases for people experiencing this issue until salesforce releases an actual fix.

Theres a few other improvements I could make, such as using the `attributtes` node to create the type, instead of using it as a parameter, and some extra null handling/error handling, but hey, it works!

```
public class GenericParser {

    public static sObject ParseSObject(String jsonString, Type typeOf) {
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString); 

        sObject record = (sObject)typeOf.newInstance();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = record.getsObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                if (fields.containsKey(parser.getText())) {

                    String label = parser.getText(); 

                    parser.nextValue();

                    Schema.SOAPType fieldType = fields.get(label).getDescribe().getSOAPType(); 

                    // Note that the enums type is not needed, just the value (TIME instead of Schema.SOAPType.TIME)
                    switch on fieldType {
                        when TIME {
                            record.put(label, ParseTime(parser.getText()));
                        } when BOOLEAN {
                            record.put(label, parser.getBooleanValue());
                        } when DOUBLE {
                            record.put(label, parser.getDoubleValue());
                        } when DATE {
                            record.put(label, parser.getDateValue());
                        } when DATETIME {
                            record.put(label, parser.getDateTimeValue());
                        } when INTEGER {
                            record.put(label, parser.getIntegerValue());
                        } when else {
                            record.put(label, parser.getText());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return record; 
    }

    public static Time ParseTime(String timeString) {
        // 14:26:41.276Z or "14:26:41.276Z"
        List<String> values = timeString.replace('Z', '').replace('"', '').split(':'); 

        // (14, 26, 41.276)         
        Integer hours = Integer.valueOf(values[0]); 
        Integer minutes = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);

        // 41.276 -> (41, 276) 
        Integer seconds = Integer.valueOf(values[2].split('\\.')[0]);
        Integer milliseconds = Integer.valueOf(values[2].split('\\.')[1]);

        return Time.newInstance(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
    }

}
```

As a bonus, it comes with a test class! I used a dummy object, with a ton of fields of just about every type, in order to ensure any field type works. Just about every `Schema.SOAPType` value is represented. Youll need to replace this with one of your own objects, but the idea is to have a generic parser, so it should work with any object & any number of fields.

```
@isTest
public class GenericParser_test {

    @isTest
    public static void Test_Time() {
        Time t = DateTime.now().Time(); 

        String j = JSON.serialize(t);

        Time r = GenericParser.ParseTime(j);

        System.assertEquals(t, r, 'Time values should be equal');
    }

    @isTest 
    public static void Test_Parser() {
        Test__c t = new Test__c(
            Account__c = '001c000001GWSaL', // Dummy Id to avoid DML 
            Opportunity__c = '006c000000GMQYv', 
            Some_Time__c = DateTime.now().Time(),
            Test_Checkbox__c = true,
            Test_Coord__latitude__s = 0,
            Test_Coord__longitude__s = 0,
            Test_Currency__c = 55.75, 
            Test_Date__c = Date.today(),
            Test_DateTime__c = DateTime.now(),
            Test_Email__c = 'example@example.com',
            Test_MultiPicklist__c = 'Test;Test 2',
            Test_Num__c = 77777755,
            Test_Percent__c = 80,
            Test_Picklist__c = 'Test',
            Test_Rich_Text__c = '<hr /><br /><b>Test</b><p>Text</p>',
            Test_TextArea__c = 'Text',
            Test_Url__c = 'example.org'
        );

        String j = JSON.serialize(t);

        sObject r = GenericParser.ParseSObject(j, Type.forName('Test__c')); 

        Test__c t2 = (Test__c)r; 

        Map<String, Object> startingValues = t.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        Map<String, Object> result = t2.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

        System.assertEquals(startingValues.keySet(), result.keySet());

        for (String key:startingValues.keySet()) {
            System.assertEquals(startingValues.get(key), result.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think some date/time handling has changed with the latest release and potentially introduced some bugs. I've got a case open for a scenario where a remoting method is returning some dates as timestamps and others as strings.

Comment: Hi guys, any update from Salesforce on it? cheers!