# JSON time fields

Tags: json, datetime, deserialize, time, serialization

We have a problem with deserialize and serialize salesforce time fields
Since Json and salesforce time fields both consist of "colon" we need to replace with a special character  before deserialize and serialize.

```
Time t = DateTime.now().Time(); 
String s = JSON.serialize(t); 

System.debug(s); // "13:50:40.848Z"

Time t2 = (Time)JSON.deserialize(s, Time.class);

System.debug(t2); // 13:50:40.848Z

Test__Test1__c test = new Test__Test1__c(
    Test__Time__c = DateTime.now().Time()
);

String testString = JSON.serialize(test);

System.debug(testString);

Test__Test1__c result = (Test__Test1__c)JSON.deserialize(testString, Test__Test1__c.class);
```

Please help me to resolve this

I got this error message

System.JSONException: Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 17:13:34.498Z or request may be missing a required field

Comment: what date format are you using in json?

Comment: Basically any date is ok but time is the problem
If serialize the datetime field into a string, I can not deserialize it. It will throw an error during deserialzatiob

Comment: can you share the code snippet over here?

Comment: I updated the question with code

Comment: `Time.parse `deserialize doesn't support in Apex, so you have to customization for deserialize by using JSONparser, i achieved by using this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220809/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-time-from-value-string-value

Comment: Thank you sdandamud1!!