# Error pushing Time from WebForm to SalesForce (Using JSForce as connector and direct REST to Push)

Tags: time, jsforce

I am building a NodeJS WebApp, that serves up a form, User  fills it out, submits it, and then pushes the data from the form to SalesForce. 
The App uses JSForce for Authentication, and then it uses a REST Connection using the Request-Promise NPM Package. Uses a PATCH Method.

Everything is pushing fine, Except a time field.

**HTML Form Field:**

```
<label>Arrived: </label> <input name="arrived" type="time">
```

**Node Varible getting data from the HTML Form**

```
var arrived = moment(req.body.arrived, "HH:mm:ss.000'Z").format("HH:mm:ss.000'Z");
```

**Push to SF**

```
function pushToSalesforce(pdfPath, address, street, jobNo, wo, result, concreteSub, cableSupplier, weather, temp, arrived, departed, date){

    console.log(arrived);

    var options = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        uri: URI + '/WorkOrder/' + wo,
        headers: {
            Authorization: Key
        },
        body: {
            "Weather__c": weather,
            "InspectionNotes__c": date,
            "Inspection_Start_Time__c": arrived,
            // "Inspection_Stop_Time__c": departed,
            "Temperature__c": temp,
            "Subcontractor__c": concreteSub,
            "Concrete_Supplier__c": cableSupplier,
            "InspectionResult__c": result
        },
        json: true
    }

    rp(options).
        then(function(parsedBody){
            console.log("SalesForce Updated");
            sendEmail(pdfPath, email, address, street, jobNo);
        }).
        catch(function(err){
            console.log("Push Failed");
            console.log(err);
        })




}
```

**Error**

```
name: 'StatusCodeError',
  statusCode: 400,
  message:
   '400 - [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 11:51:00.000\'+00
  error:
   [ { message:
        'Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 11:51:00.000\'+00:00 or request
       errorCode: 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR' } ],
```

The Field it is pushing to is a Time Field, i get the same error with Time & DateTime

I Re-Wrote it using the APEX instead of straight Rest and no change.

```
 conn.login(username, password, function (err, userInfo) {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            Key = "Bearer " + conn.accessToken;
            // logged in user property
            console.log("Access Token: " + conn.accessToken);
            console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
            console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
            // ...
            conn.sobject("WorkOrder").update({
                Id: wo,
                Weather__c: weather,
                InspectionNotes__c: date,
                Inspection_Start_Time__c: arrived,
                // Inspection_Stop_Time__c : departed,
                Temperature__c: temp,
                Subcontractor__c: concreteSub,
                Concrete_Supplier__c: cableSupplier,
                InspectionResult__c: result
            }, function (err, ret) {
                if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
                console.log('Updated Successfully : ' + ret.id);
                // sendEmail(pdfPath, email, address, street, jobNo);
            });
        });
```

Error:

```
JSON_PARSER_ERROR: Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value 12:30:00.000'-05:00 or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:103]
    at HttpApi.getError (C:\Users\ezekiel\Documents\Projects\inspections-web-form\node_modules\jsforce\lib\http-api.js:250:13)
    at C:\Users\ezekiel\Documents\Projects\inspections-web-form\node_modules\jsforce\lib\http-api.js:95:22
    at tryCallOne (C:\Users\ezekiel\Documents\Projects\inspections-web-form\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:37:12)
    at C:\Users\ezekiel\Documents\Projects\inspections-web-form\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:123:15
    at flush (C:\Users\ezekiel\Documents\Projects\inspections-web-form\node_modules\asap\raw.js:50:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  name: 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR',
  errorCode: 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR'
} undefined
```

I have seen: [Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE_STRING value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220809/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-time-from-value-string-value)

However this doesn't help me, May just be that i do not have enough experience to convert it from C# to NodeJS, but it is still not helpful at this point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize instance of time from VALUE\_STRING value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220809/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-time-from-value-string-value)

Comment: Unfortunately not, It may just be because i have been unable to successfully rewrite all this in Javascript instead of C#